# Android Things - Raspberry Pi Fails to Connect to Wifi

Tags: android, wifi, raspberry-pi3, android-things

There are a few questions out there that have similar issues but none of the solutions help.  I'm trying to connect an Android Things Raspberry Pi to Wifi.  My 2.4 GHz wifi ssid is 'cake' and I even removed the passphrase to see if that would help.  Here is what comes out in the logcat:

```
09-20 01:37:00.340  1233  1233 D WifiSetupService: onStartCommand(Intent { act=WifiSetupService.Connect cmp=com.google.wifisetup/.WifiSetupService (has extras) })
09-20 01:37:00.341  1233  1233 I WifiConfigurator: Connecting to network with SSID "cake"
09-20 01:37:00.345  1233  1251 W WifiManager: com.google.wifisetup attempted call to setWifiApEnabled: enabled = false
09-20 01:37:00.346   311   546 D WifiService: setWifiEnabled: true pid=1233, uid=1000, package=com.google.wifisetup
09-20 01:37:00.349  1233  1233 V WifiWatcher: Network state changed to DISCONNECTED
09-20 01:37:01.258  1233  1251 D WifiConfigurator: Adding new network
09-20 01:37:01.873   311   380 E WifiConfigManager: Cannot find network with networkId -1 or configKey "cake"NONE
09-20 01:37:01.874   311   380 E WifiConfigManager: Cannot find network with configKey "cake"NONE
09-20 01:37:02.648   311   323 D WificondControl: Scan result ready event
09-20 01:37:03.423   311   380 D WifiConfigStore: Writing to stores completed in 1304 ms.
09-20 01:37:03.430   311   380 D WifiStateMachine: connectToUserSelectNetwork netId 0, uid 1000, forceReconnect = false
09-20 01:37:04.261   311   380 D WifiConfigStore: Writing to stores completed in 823 ms.
09-20 01:37:34.306  1233  1251 E WifiConfigurator: Wifi failed to connect in 30000 ms
09-20 01:39:49.672  1233  1233 D WifiSetupService: onStartCommand(Intent { act=WifiSetupService.Connect cmp=com.google.wifisetup/.WifiSetupService (has extras) })
09-20 01:39:49.673  1233  1233 I WifiConfigurator: Connecting to network with SSID "cake"
09-20 01:39:49.675  1233  1279 W WifiManager: com.google.wifisetup attempted call to setWifiApEnabled: enabled = false
09-20 01:39:49.676   311   322 D WifiService: setWifiEnabled: true pid=1233, uid=1000, package=com.google.wifisetup
09-20 01:39:49.681  1233  1279 D WifiConfigurator: Updating existing network 0
09-20 01:39:49.906   311   380 D WifiConfigStore: Writing to stores completed in 219 ms.
09-20 01:39:49.909   311   380 D WifiStateMachine: connectToUserSelectNetwork netId 0, uid 1000, forceReconnect = false
09-20 01:39:49.945   311   380 D WifiConfigStore: Writing to stores completed in 32 ms.
09-20 01:39:50.195   311   920 D WificondControl: Scan result ready event
09-20 01:40:19.980  1233  1279 E WifiConfigurator: Wifi failed to connect in 30000 ms
```

Here is what I'm typing in the adb shell

```
rpi3:/ $ am startservice -n com.google.wifisetup/.WifiSetupService -a WifiSetupService.Connect -e ssid cake
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had also some issues setting up the Wifi. 
Blundell's answer to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46225713/wifi-setup-not-possible-on-raspberry-pi-3/46245670?noredirect=1#comment79467890_46245670) solved the issues

> Network: Wi-Fi cannot connect to the internet if Ethernet is also
>   connected to a network without internet access.

https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html

I had to remove the Ethernet cable from the Pi-3 and then it connected to my WiFi

---

If you have no application installed on the Pi you can observce your connectivity state by attaching an external display using the HDMI port (a monitor would do the job).

You should see a screen like this:[image]

Comment: Yeah but how did you discover the IP address after you removed the ethernet cable from it?

Comment: The easiest way: You could connect your raspberry via hdmi to monitor

Comment: That did it!  Thanks...such a ridiculous thing to not mention in the docs.

Comment: This trick works on the NXP i.MX7D Android things development kit as well. Thanks!